# Get rid of unnecessary conditions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I define a piecewise function as

```
g[x_] := 
  Piecewise[
   {{lambda * Exp[lambda *(x - nBar)]/(1 - Exp[lambda*(nUnder - nBar)]), 
     nUnder <= x <= nBar}}, 0]
```

I would like to define and compute another function `g2`, assuming that `0 < nUnder < nBar`:

$$g_2(x) = \int g(s-t)g(t)dt$$

```
g2[s_] := Assuming[{nBar - nUnder > 0}, Integrate[g[s - x]*g[x], {x, nUnder, nBar}]]
g2[s]
```

The output is

[image: func]

or

> ```
> Piecewise[
>   {{-((E^(lambda*s)*lambda^2*(-2*nBar + s))/(E^(lambda*nBar) - E^(lambda*nUnder))^2), 
>     nBar - nUnder > 0 && nBar + nUnder - s < 0 && 2*nBar - s > 0}, 
>    {(E^(lambda*s)*lambda^2*(-2*nUnder + s))/(E^(lambda*nBar) - E^(lambda*nUnder))^2, 
>     (nBar + nUnder - s == 0 && nBar - nUnder > 0) || 
>     (nBar + nUnder - s >= 0 && nBar - nUnder > 0 && 
>     2*nUnder - s < 0)}}, 
>   0]
> ```

in input form.

As you can see, it keeps iterating the assumption `nBar - nUnder > 0` — but I thought I enforced that by using `Assuming`?

1. How can I simplify `g2` to permanently work under the assumption `nBar > nUnder > 0`? `Simplify` was of no help.
2. Similarly, it would help to redefine `g2` for the domain `2 nUnder <= s <= 2 nBar`, to get rid of some other of the conditions. Can I achieve that somehow?

Comment: I can't post the question with latex - the system keeps telling me that there is unformatted code in the question...

Comment: I've replaced the TeX with an image.  Roll back if you prefer.

Comment: @MichaelE2. think it's my image of the outpu that replaced it :-)

Comment: @m_goldberg The edit history says you replaced my image with yours -- simultaneous editing. :)

Answer (score 3):

Include [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) in definition of `g2`

```
g[x_] := Piecewise[{{lambda*
     Exp[lambda*(x - nBar)]/(1 - Exp[lambda*(nUnder - nBar)]), 
    nUnder <= x <= nBar}}, 0]

g2[s_] = Assuming[{nBar > nUnder > 0},
  Integrate[g[s - x]*g[x], {x, nUnder, nBar}] //
   Simplify]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the Piecewise definition and only integrate over the required region.

```
g2[x_] := lambda*Exp[lambda*(x - nBar)]/(1 - Exp[lambda*(nUnder - nBar)])

Integrate[g2[x], {x, nUnder, nBar}]

Integrate[g2[s - x]*g2[x], {x, Max[nUnder, s - nUnder], Min[s - nBar, nbar]}]
```

Comment: `Integrate[g2[s - x]*g2[x], {x, nUnder, nBar}]` ensures that `g2[x]` is only integrated over the required domain, but `g2[s-x]` in general is not necessarily inside the required domain.

Comment: So you need to integrate only when both x and s-x are between nUnder and nBar?

Comment: Yes, that is the case.